# Html form doesn't respond of hitting Enter

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm writing backend of my site on nodeJS using express. There is search form there. After I type in name of the object I'm looking for I press Enter button, but form is not responding. I've read similar posts here, but there is no working solution for my case. 
Here is form

```
    <div>
      <form action="/options/searchres" method="GET"></form>
       <input type="text"  name="name" placeholder="Search..">
       <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1">
      </form>
   </div>
```

So I have app.js file with router options (websitename/options/search)
here is router options.js code

```
    router.get("/search", (req, res) => {
    res.render('search');
    });
    router.get("/searchres", (req, res) => {
    academies.getAll()
    .then(data => {
    let object = data;
    let dat = {
        academies: academies,
        page: req.query.page,
        searchname: req.query.name
    };

    academies.getByName(req.query.name)
        .then(data => {
            dat.academies = data;
            // console.log(data);
            res.render('searchres', dat);
         })
       });
    });
```

Comment: You immediately close your form after the opening tag: `<form action="/options/searchres" method="GET"></form>` Everything else is outside the form thus your form has no submit input => no reaction on enter

Comment: @Psi, thanks, I've misprinted that closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things you need to change

1. You closed the `<form>` tag too early. That is why you couldn't submit anything
2. The first `input` has two types, remove the `submit` one

The code below

```
<div>
  <form action="/options/searchres" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search..">
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's just VScode intellisense closed that tag too early.